# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'tuple'

Tags: python, arrays, while-loop, tuples, cx-oracle

Whenever i try to run this code it get TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'tuple' error since it returns int and saves as a tuple and when i try to assign the returned value
it acts as if its not an integer that you can't use "< > + = - " for it

```
  import cx_Oracle

  conn = cx_Oracle.connect('emu/emu@127.0.0.1')
  cur = conn.cursor()
  cur.execute("select max(locationid) from location")
  for line in cur:
      maxID = line
  IDofcity = 1
  while IDofcity < maxID:
      cur.execute(f"select city from location where locationid='{IDofcity}'")
      for row in cur:
          Nameofcities = ['']
          Nameofcities.append(row)

  IDofcity += 1

  print(Nameofcities)

  cur.close()
  conn.close()
```

Code & Error

[image]

Comment: Even though you're using an SQL aggregate function, the database row is a tuple, not an integer. Try `maxID = line[0]`. In the future, you can diagnose such problems more easily by running a static analyzer like mypy over your code or even just printing the value that doesn't seem to be what you think it should be to STDOUT.

Comment: @JaredSmith still it is not working

Comment: Does it come up with the same error even when you use `maxID = line[0]`?

Comment: @WilliamTorkington it goes into an infinite loop without giving any error

Comment: I believe the answer for the actual problem has already been given.  I wanted to add that using `'{IDofcity}'` is a performance issue and a security risk.  Read the [cx_Oracle manual](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```py
for line in cur:
  (maxID,) = line
```

This makes maxID reference the value in the tuple instead of the tuple itself.

If there are more than 1 items in the tuple you will get:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1)
```

Comment: still it goes into an endless loop